# Get the information of the users who answered the survey in the Telegram group

Tags: python, api, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I am using telethon api for get data from telegram .
I want to get the information of the users who voted for the poll I made in my telegram group. Is this possible?
Also I tried to get on channel but I cant

Thanks

For more information :https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_poll_votes.html

Comment: Yes, it's possible, the request you linked is the right one. What code have you tried?

Comment: I can get how many responses to a questionnaire have been answered. With the PollAnswerVoters field

An example 
PollResults(min=False, results=[PollAnswerVoters(option=b'0', voters=0, chosen=False, correct=False)
BUT 
Im looking for who voted and which option not statistically.I want to know which users voted .Number name .

    result = await client(functions.messages.GetPollVotesRequest(
        peer='Ys-Channel',  #channel name 
        id=10, #message id 
        limit=100,
        option=None,
        offset=None
    ))
    Get Broadcast error -

Comment: `GetPollVotesRequest` should tell you in the `user` list of the response, if the poll is public. Make sure all the input parameters are correct (channel, poll ID, etc.). I'm not sure what the poll ID is, but it's probably either the message ID or the poll ID.